# How can I add new columns and rows to a database?

Tags: android

How can I create more columns and add data to them?

So far I can add like so:

```
private static final String INSERT="insert into "+ TABLE_NAME +"(name,address)values(?,?)";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything using simple `insert` and `select` query?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add column in your SQL create table syntax 
refer to this link http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

Comment: ya i wanna add column and row